# Within the number of different ways to order in line the letters of the word LOVEPONIXO, in how many ways there are no two O's one after another?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Within the number of different ways to order in line the letters of the word LOVEPONIXO, in how many ways there are no two O's one after another?
I was thinking - there are $\frac{10!}{3!}$ different ways to order the letters. Then I want to subtract the number of ways that include two O's one after another:  $2!\cdot\frac{9!}{3!}$
And then I want to subtract the number of ways that include three O's on after another (some of them are included in the last calculation) : $3!\cdot\frac{8!}{3!}$
Then I get a final answer: $\frac{10!}{3!}-2!\cdot\frac{9!}{3!}-3!\cdot\frac{8!}{3!} = 8\cdot\frac{9!}{3!}-8!$
I have a strong feeling that I did something wrong though... Any directions?

Comment: Be careful.  The E's are also repeated.

Comment: I'm so sorry! The word is LOVEPONIXO

Comment: It looks like you created more than one account.  You should [merge](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) them since having a higher reputation gives you more privileges on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler method of doing the problem is to set aside the three O's for the moment.  There are $7!$ ways of arranging the other seven letters since they are distinct.  For any given arrangement, we now have eight gaps, six between successive letters and the two ends, in which to place the three O's.  We can place the O's in these gaps in $\binom{8}{3}$ ways.  Hence, the number of permutations in which no two O's are consecutive is 
$$7! \cdot \binom{8}{3}$$

The method you attempted can be made to work.  As you observed, there are $$\frac{10!}{3!}$$ distinguishable arrangements of the letters.  From these, we must exclude those in which at least two O's are consecutive.

Suppose two O's are consecutive.  We treat them as one letter, say $\cal{O}$.  Thus, we have nine objects to arrange.  Since they are distinct, they can be arranged in $9!$ ways.

However, when we subtract those arrangements in which at least two O's are consecutive, we remove those arrangements in which three O's are consecutive twice.  Therefore, we must add them back in.  If we treat the three O's as one object, we have eight distinct objects to arrange, which can be done in $8!$ ways.

Thus, by the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the number of distinct permutations of LOVEPONIXO in which no two O's are consecutive is 
$$\frac{10!}{3!} - 9! + 8!$$
As you can verify by direct calculation, this agrees with the answer given above.

Comment: Wow. Amazing. How do I think like this next time? :(

Comment: But wait... this way you're gonna have repeats! I think you should divide by $3!$

Comment: We do not have to divide my first answer by $3!$ since we are choosing three locations in which to place three identical letters after the other letters have been arranged.  The $3!$ ways in which we could interchange the three O's that have been placed in the gaps do not change the order of the letters in the permutation since the O's are indistinguishable.  As for how you think this way, you study the solution and try to apply it when you are confronted with a similar problem.

Comment: Ok I'm trying to understand the second part of your answer... But I think something is not right. If you add options where 3 O's are successive, then you now have options with 2 O's that are successive. This is a problem... No 2 successive O's means not two, not three, not ........

Comment: When we remove those arrangements in which at least two O's are consecutive, we remove those in which all three O's are consecutive twice, once when we remove the first two O's and once when we remove the last two O's.  Thus, when we subtract those arrangements in which two O's are consecutive, we subtract the number of arrangements in which three O's are consecutive twice.  However, we only want to subtract them once.  Thus, we must add the number of arrangements in which all three O's are consecutive so that they are only subtracted once.